# LevelDB based mqtt-level-store does not clean deleted data from filesystem

Tags: node.js, mqtt, leveldb

I'm using [mqtt.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) with [mqtt-level-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt-level-store). I have no idea of how leveldb is being used here and how it works.

mqtt.js puts data in the store and removes it once it is successfully uploaded.

I kept my device offline for 2 days and let it gather data in the store (140 KB every minute)

After I put it online, it uploaded a lot of data and then stopped. Now it was only uploading the new incoming data, so I guess it uploaded everything.

However, before putting the device online, I saw there were files of about 230 MB.
After all of the uploading completed, the files were still there. After few more fresh data uploads, some of the files were removed, however, there are still files of about 190 MB.

Is there a setting I am missing? How does this cleanup happen?

Answer (score 1):

From  [Google documentation](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/impl.md) we know that compaction of db provided

> When the size of level L exceeds its limit, we compact it in a background thread. The compaction picks a file from level L and all overlapping files from the next level L+1. Note that if a level-L file overlaps only part of a level-(L+1) file, the entire file at level-(L+1) is used as an input to the compaction and will be discarded after the compaction.
>
> . . .
>
> **DeleteObsoleteFiles()** is called at the end of every compaction and at the end of recovery.

From my experience you need to wait a bit. DB will be cleaned up somewhere in time.